# Is it sensible to run a Socket.IO setImmediate loop for each connected player?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Instead of a game loop, I want something different: My game does not have much action going on; just moving users over a tile map with correct timers in between.

Since I am using Socket.IO, I want to run a "mini game loop" inside the `io.sockets.on("connected"`-part of my script. I am thinking to run a `setImmediate` checking a few variables to know what to do with the player.

The way I understand socket.IO, it would create this `setImmediate` function for each client that joins the server. (Because it runs inside the "connected" event handler.)

Let's say 1000 players join the game. If what I fear is true, this approach seems bad. Have I misunderstood `setImmediate`?

Comment: It is late at night. Tell me if this makes no sense, so I can edit it.

Comment: Your server architecture should strive to maintain asynchronous reading/writing capabilities for each client that is connected to it, as well as the ability to manage the overall state of the game. The issue with your suggestion is that it ties together the game logic with the networking back end. Ideally your game should simply talk to the networking back end through a facade, while the actual implementation is kept decoupled, and maintainable.

Comment: So what you are saying is: Gameloop & for gods sake don't block the IO ? :)

Comment: Dont block the IO, and try to separate the game code from your networking back end. There is always going to be a point where your game code has to talk to the networking code, and this is where the facade comes in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket.io will emit `connected` event for every connected socket. So in your case you will create loads of loops there.
It is better to have list of sockets, and one loop separately.

As you've said - your case is simple - so keep it simple, do not overcomplicate.

```
var sockets = { };

server.on('connected', function(socket) {
    // runs for every connection
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete sockets[socket.id];
    }
});

var UPS = 20;
var gameLoop = setInterval(function() {
    var socket;
    for(var id in sockets) {
        socket = sockets[id];
        // ...
    }
}, 1000 / UPS);
```

Comment: Hehe, this is a year old! Have some Karma that you came for and get out :p

Comment: It's actually how I do it these days. That, and/or Array Iteration.

Comment: @Maksims Mihejevs @Oliver Schöning This looks very simple compared to the client side game loop, which may have `requestAnimationFrame` and delta time in the animation function. Is there a reason that the server side gameloop just need to be in a simple `setInterval` function or is this just the best we could do on the server side?

Comment: requestAnimationFrame tries it's best to provide callback before rendering and prevents reflowing DOM during that method when dealing with styles and DOM structure.
So it is recommended to use requestAnimationFrame on client.
You server side logic frequency shall not depend on client side frequency, and vice versa.
Server side, requestAnimationFrame - is not relevant, as there is no rendering going on.